# NLP strategy for categorizing multiple multi-word phrases in context in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I'd like some help choosing an NLP strategy for categorizing journal entries. Here's an example of what a journal entry might look like and what a correct categorization would be.

"Yesterday, I got terrible sleep. I felt pretty tired, so my productivity for the day wasn't very good."

Categorization: "Sleep: terrible" and "Productivity: wasn't very good"

I have a large set of personal journals. people are going to be talking about things they've done (or tried to do) and how it worked out ("good", "bad"). There will be multiple attempts and ratings per entry and i need to match them correctly.

Now, one approach I could take is to use Spacy's matcher in Python and come up with a list of multi-word attributes, like

```
# Initialize the Matcher with the shared vocabulary
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Create a pattern matching two tokens: "iPhone" and "X"
pattern = [{'TEXT': 'not'}, {'TEXT': 'very'}, {'TEXT': 'good'}]
```

But, the question is, even if I come up with a new dictionary of ratings and elements, how do I match them in context, like the right attribute/adjective/rating with the correct element (like productivity or sleep).

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this but I'm not quite sure. Any help would be great and let me know if I can make this question better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in); your question is too broad for Stack Overflow, but might fit elsewhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: As a tip, the technical name for what you're trying to do is "aspect based sentiment analysis". It's an area of active research and you'll probably have to try a few things before you can find anything that works (if you do). One big question is, do you have a fixed list of contexts or do you want to handle anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but my reputation is too low, but this is a really interesting application of NLP. If your journal already has categories I would look into an ML approach. My favorite tool for text categorization is fasttext (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html)

Anyway, good luck with this!